# Issue with Julia ccall interface and symbols

Tags: julia

I'm attemping to use Julia's `ccall` function to interface with a C library. All the types and pointers are correct, and the below function call successfully returns the correct answer (variable defintion and setup not shown here for brevity).

```
    ccall((:vDSP_convD, libacc),  Void,
          (Ptr{T}, Int64,  Ptr{T},  Int64,  Ptr{T},  Int64, UInt64, UInt64),
          x_padded, 1, pointer(K, Ksize), -1, result, 1,  Rsize, Ksize)
```

However, if I wish to generate the function name as a symbol, and then use it as an argument to `ccall`, it fails.

```
fname = symbol(string("vDSP_conv", "D"))
ccall((fname , libacc),  Void,
          (Ptr{T}, Int64,  Ptr{T},  Int64,  Ptr{T},  Int64, UInt64, UInt64),
          x_padded, 1, pointer(K, Ksize), -1, result, 1,  Rsize, Ksize)
```

The error is:

```
ERROR: LoadError: TypeError: conv: in ccall: first argument not a 
pointer or valid constant expression, expected Ptr{T}, 
got Tuple{Symbol,ASCIIString}
```

If I print the type of each of these two naming versions, I get

```
julia> println(typeof(:vDSP_convD))
       Symbol
julia> println(typeof(fname))
       Symbol
```

Is there a way to get this to work? I'm guessing that I will have to wrap this in a macro or `@eval` to get this work, but I am curious as to why the above functionality doesn't work as shown?

Any help will be most appreciated!

**EDIT**

I ended up wrapping this in an `@eval` block to get it to work; however, I'm still curious as to the backend logic as to why the above syntax doesn't work (why it interprets a symbol as a pointer sometimes, and then not other times)

Comment: as the doc says ["(:function, “library”) pair must be constant"](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#calling-c-and-fortran-code)

Comment: Is there a way to make this work using `const` or `Pair()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ccall` is not really a function – it's a syntactic form that is translated to a C function call using the C ABI. To emit a call to a C function, you need to be able to statically resolve the address of the function – that's where this requirement comes from. Note that in both C and Julia you can also call a function using a variable function pointer. In Julia, there are a few ways to get such a pointer, typically by using `dlopen` and `dlsym`. What `ccall` won't do is resolve a function by non-constant name: this is impossible in C (without a building yourself a lookup table); in Julia you can do this, as you've figured out, by using `eval` – but there is compiler overhead to doing this. That is why `ccall` won't do this automatically: you don't want to run the risk of accidentally introducing compiler overhead in a loop, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the illustrative explanation of `ccall`; explains everything that I wanted to know!