# Avoid an extra begin block when quoting in a macro

Tags: julia, metaprogramming, ffi

I am writing a Julia macro like this:

```
macro cfunc(name, rettype)
  quotedname = Expr(:quote, name)
  return quote 
    (()->ccall(($quotedname, "libc.so.6"), $rettype, ()))
  end
end
```

and I am able to use it to create a function:

```
@cfunc(time, Int32)()  # Returns current time
```

However, if I factor out the quoting macro:

```
macro q(name)
  sym = Expr(:quote,name)
  return quote
    $(sym)
  end
end
```

`macroexpand` produces an extra begin and end:

```
:((begin
      #= REPL[142]:4 =#
      ()->begin
              #= REPL[142]:4 =#
              ccall((begin # <-- This is the extra begin
                          #= REPL[102]:4 =#
                          :clock
                      end, "libc.so.6"), Main.Int32, ())
          end       # ^^^ This is the extra end
  end)())
```

which causes ccall to fail:

```
@cfunc(time, Int32)()
ERROR: error compiling #26: unsupported or misplaced expression "block" in function #26
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[151]:4
```

How can I avoid the begin/end when quoting like this?

Answer (score 1):

The `quote` block in the `q` macro introduces the extra `begin` and `end` in the fully expanded version. It normally shouldn't affect the result, but [ccall is special](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35835289/4508007).

This works:

```
macro q(name)
  sym = Expr(:quote,name)
  return sym
end
```

as does this quote form that does not introduce a `begin`/`end`:

```
macro q(name)
  sym = Expr(:quote,name)
  return :($sym)
end
```